# How to put a \clubsuit at the end of an example

Tags: theorems

I was wondering if there was an easy set of code that allows the standard `\begin{example}` `\end{example}` environment in `amsthm` to have the extra feature that it right-aligns a `\clubsuit` at the end of the example? Similarly, I would like to perform the exact same modification to the remark environment but with a `\diamond` instead of a `\clubsuit`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to check out the `ntheorem` package.  A couple of examples lifted from page 17 of the documentation that can be customized:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{change}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\theoremstyle{change}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{:}
% \theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
% for tohecz
\theoremsymbol{\makebox[7.7778pt][c]{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Here's an example
\end{example}

\begin{remark}
Here's a remark
\end{remark}

\begin{Proof}
Here is a proof
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am having a little difficulty fixing a problem. I copied and pasted the code into my file and when I tried to compile I got the error "##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}" and when I click 'go to error' it takes me to a .sty file which is "locked". I apologize for asking what is, perhaps, a very stupid question, I am just absolutely over my head when I get into anything non-superficial with tex. Thank you so much!

Comment: Update: So after looking at the documentation it appears that I have to remove amsthm to apply this package. I did so, but then got errors on all of my \begin{proof}. I don't know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm sorry but it's hard to tell what might be causing your error.  If you could post a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that might help to figure out what is causing the error (although I know very little about the `ntheorem` package outside of what I posted.

Comment: I don't think that `ntheorem` comes with a predefined proof environment, you may need to create one yourself.  See the updated code.

Comment: +1 I don't like `ntheorem` but this works pretty good. Just one idea: the black squeare should be centered below the two suits, so that the result is more visually appealing ;)