# Example with clubsuit (no ntheorem)

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm

I would like an example environment which is numbered according to theorems (e.g. theorem 1, example 2, theorem 3, example 4, ...) and ends with a clubsuit. I've already seen this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99548/how-to-put-a-clubsuit-at-the-end-of-an-example), but I would rather have one which doesn't use the `ntheorem` package; either by creating a new environment, or by rewriting the existing one (e.g. the proof environment). I'm not particularly experienced with LaTex, so I'm asking this.

This is the code I have so I can get started. I can live with the error for now.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newenvironment{example}{\paragraph{Example:}}{\hfill$\clubsuit$\vspace{10pt}}
% produces Error: Command \example already defined.
```

It mostly works. It is numbered according to theorem, and ends with a clubsuit:

```
\begin{example}
    First example.
\end{example}
```

[image: first example]

However, there are some issues, as illustrated below:

```
\begin{example}
    Second example.
\end{example}
Line after second example breaks it.
```

[image]
This can be fixed by adding a new line as follows:

```
\begin{example}
    Third example.
\end{example}

A line after a newline after the third example is okay.
```

[image]
But I'd rather not have to do this fix in the first place. Also, the environment doesn't work with equations.

```
\begin{example}
    Example ending on an equation (qedhere does not work)
    \begin{equation*}
        a = b.
    \end{equation*}
\end{example}
```

[image]
Unlike the `proof` environment, `\qedhere` does not work. Similar issue goes with itemize/enumerate. In summary, I would like a minimal, non-`ntheorem`-based `example` environment, which is essentially a copy of the proof environment, but the QED symbol is replaced by a clubsuit (such that the `\qedhere` command or equivalent can bring the clubsuit into an ending equation). I'm sure there is a simpler solution than what I have.

---

**Update.** The following solution adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978/165455) is very close to what I want:

```
\newcommand{\newmarkedtheorem}[1]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}
    {\pushQED{\hfill$\clubsuit$}\csname inner@#1\endcsname}
    {\popQED\csname endinner@#1\endcsname}%
  \newtheorem{inner@#1}%
}
\newmarkedtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
```

However, there is still an issue with the `equation` and `align` environments.

```
\begin{example}
    Example ending in align environment:
    \begin{align*}
        1 + 1 + 1 &= 1 + 2\\
        &= 3.\qedhere
    \end{align*}
\end{example}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help? [How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978)

Comment: @barbarabeeton it does. Thank you!

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for the link. I may have spoke too soon earlier (in terms of completely solving the problem). I'm doing some more tests with the align environment.

Comment: What's important in applying `\qedhere` is putting it in the right place.  Since you always want to change the qed box to the clubsuit, you might want to define a `\clubhere` that resets the symbol and then goes on to do the rest of what `\qedhere` does, namely the change of location.  (I thought that was covered in the answer I linked.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not familiar with LaTeX syntax. How can I define `\clubhere` with that functionality? That might very well solve the issue I'm having right now (see update). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `\pushQED{\hfill$\clubsuit$}`. You really need `\pushQED{\qed}` or to define something else along the line of `\qed`.

The easiest way is to add an optional argument for the symbol to use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\newmarkedtheorem}[2][\openbox]{%
  \newenvironment{#2}
    {\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{#1}\pushQED{\qed}\csname inner@#2\endcsname}
    {\popQED\csname endinner@#2\endcsname}%
  \newtheorem{inner@#2}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newmarkedtheorem[$\clubsuit$]{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newmarkedtheorem[$\diamondsuit$]{exercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
An example.
\end{example}

\begin{exercise}
An exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{example}
    Example ending in align environment:
    \begin{align*}
        1 + 1 + 1 &= 1 + 2\\
        &= 3.\qedhere
    \end{align*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using no optional argument would default to the standard `\openbox`.